# how to set a global varible from a request in case of concurrent requests

Tags: node.js, express

I am doing dynamic routing my app using a middleware in Node and express. So, I am extracting params from the req to resolve the routes.
Middleware looks something like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
global.c_name = req.params.c;
next();
 });

router.get('/a/:m/:controller/:action',(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    var controller = "./f/leg/fe/clients/"+req.params.c+"/main/process/"+req.params.m+"/controllers/"+req.params.controller;
    var controller_class = require(controller);
    console.log(controller);
    var controllerObj = new controller_class();
    var action = req.params.action;
    res.send(controllerObj[action]());
});
```

app.js

```
app.use('/:c/',middleware);
```

My problem is, in case of concurrent requests, the `global.c_name` variable will be overwritten by another request and that will ruin everything. How can I avoid this? I have to do this dynamically.

Comment: You can store c_name in express session

Comment: This seem like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you saving a request property to the global object? You posted  two routes, but only used it in one? What's the significance of the second route?

Comment: Why do you want to retain value of c ?

Comment: @MarkMeyer The first route is only there to get the name of the client and store it in a global variable so that it can be accessed throughout in require statements. The project uses various levels of inheritance and since the routing is dynamic, we need require statements accordingly.

Comment: Only second route is used to resolve the request and send response.

Comment: If you want to save state *between requests*, you need to store something on client, not the server. This is why we have cookies and local storage. After all, a user can make a request and then wait five minutes before making another. If you are trying to save a variable for the life of a *single request* as it moves through the middleware you can save it on the `res` object in something like `res.locals`

Comment: Time to learn about sessions.

Comment: @MarkMeyer res.locals is only visible inside views. And isn't session also created with incoming requests, how can that help?

Comment: @properchels res.locals is available anywhere `res` is available, so anywhere in the middleware chain. It’s still not clear to me if the OP is trying to save state within a single request or between requests.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes it's available wherever res is available, but I need access to it in my controllerObj for require() statements. The whole purpose of making c_name global is so that require statements in controllerObj can resolve path using the client name obtained from the request. Problem arises when another req hits while it is still resolving the previous one as in that case, the global variable will be overwritten by the new incoming request and that will eventually lead to wrong destination.

Comment: @properchels,  from your example it's very hard to understand why you need the global. You seem to be making your controller by using  `req.params.c` directly: `var controller = "./f/leg/fe/clients/"+req.params.c+"/main/process/"+req.params.m+"/controllers/"+req.params.controller;` (p.s. it seems like a bad idea to trust data from the client like this, but that's a different question). Si